# Linked list doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, linked-list

I implemented this code to add an item to the list (it must be a string) and remove a specific string. However it has two problems: FIRST, the order is wrong after insert the nodes to the list. SECOND, after removing a node, it remains a "blank" space, see below when I remove the Third node.

Initial list:
First
Fourth
Third
Second

After list_remove():
First
Fourth

Second

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myStruct {
    char str[20];
    struct myStruct * pNext;
};

struct myStruct *list_create(const char *str)
{
    struct myStruct *node;

    if(!(node=malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct)))) 
        return NULL;
    strcpy(node->str, str);
    node->pNext = NULL;

    return node;
}

int add_to(struct myStruct * list, const char *str)
{
    struct myStruct *newnode;

    newnode = list_create(str);
    newnode->pNext = list->pNext;
    list->pNext = newnode;

    return 1;
}

char * remove_to(struct myStruct * list, const char *str)
{
    while(list->pNext && (strcmp(list->str, str))) 
        list = list->pNext;

    free(list);    

    return 0;
}

int list_foreach(struct myStruct *node, int(*func)(void*))
{
    while(node) {
        if(func(node->str)!=0) return -1;
        node=node->pNext;
    }
    return 0;
}

int printstring(void *s)
{
    printf("%s\n", (char *)s);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct myStruct *list;

    // Create initial elements of list 
    list = list_create("First");
    add_to(list, "Second");
    add_to(list, "Third");
    add_to(list, "Fourth");

    printf("Initial list:\n");
    list_foreach(list, printstring);
    putchar('\n');

    remove_to(list, "Third");
    printf("After list_remove():\n");
    list_foreach(list, printstring);
    putchar('\n');    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest learning how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see a few problems:
add_to() always operates on the current list's first item. So every time you add, the new node will be  inserted between the first and second (if there is a second).

And the method remove_to does not check if a matching string was actually found. After exhausting the while loop, if not match was found, I think you will free the last item.

C++ has a whole suite of "Collections" and a built in linked list is one of them. Unless this is a homework exercise where you have to implement your own, consider using that.